# Can I use the Lag function against a custom member

Tags: mdx

In the following I successfully find the last complete month and the billable income related to that month. Then I'd like to target the month before and find the income for that month. Thought that `Lag` would be a good function to use but this doesn't seem to work. No errors just no data returned for the second column `[Measures].[PrevMth_BillInc]`:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth] AS
    IIF(
       Day(Now()) = 1,
       TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2).Item(1),
       TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2).Item(0)
       )
MEMBER [Measures].[LastMth_BillInc] AS
    SUM(
       [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth],
       [Measures].[BillableIncome]
       )
MEMBER [Measures].[PrevMth_BillInc] AS
    SUM(
       [Date].[LastMth].Lag(1),
       [Measures].[BillableIncome]
       )
SELECT
    NON EMPTY 
        {
        [Measures].[LastMth_BillInc],
        [Measures].[PrevMth_BillInc] //<<<<<this returns nothing
        } 
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
        ORDER( 
            [Customer_Dim].[Customer_Hier].[Customer_Level].Members,
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth],
            BDESC
            ) 
    ON ROWS 
FROM [ourCube]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining `[LastMth]` as a calculated member, you define a new member of the `[Date].[Date - Calendar Month]`, not an alias to an existing one. Hence `Lag` does not work, as it is applied to the new member - which is somewhere in the hierarchy alongside the original member. And as `Lag` is a function which operates on the hierarchy structure,  it is not to the original member used in its definition.

You could get around that by defining LastMth as a set which would contain the original, non calculated member (to be exact, it would contain a tuple containing the original member) as follows:

```
WITH
SET [LastTwo] AS
    TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2)
SET [LastMonth] AS
    IIF(
       Day(Now()) = 1,
       Subset([LastTwo], 1, 1),
       Subset([LastTwo], 0, 1)
       )
MEMBER [Measures].[LastMth_BillInc] AS
       (
       [LastMth].Item(0).Item(0),
       [Measures].[BillableIncome]
       )
MEMBER [Measures].[PrevMth_BillInc] AS
       (
       [LastMth].ITEM(0).Item(0).Lag(2),
       [Measures].[BillableIncome]
       )
SELECT
    NON EMPTY 
        {
        [Measures].[LastMth_BillInc],
        [Measures].[PrevMth_BillInc]
        } 
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
        ORDER( 
            [Customer_Dim].[Customer_Hier].[Customer_Level].Members,
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth],
            BDESC
            ) 
    ON ROWS 
FROM [ourCube]
```

I think you do not need `sum`, you can just use tuples as I did above, as there is only one member and not a set of several to be summed.

Comment: @FrankPI ....your answer still returns an empty set of results - can I edit your answer to the answer which works?

Comment: @FrankPI - so when I create a `SET` in `WITH` it seems to be aware of the hierarchy it came from whereas if I create a member it is unaware?

Comment: @whytheq Yes, I edited my answer to explain this more detailed.

Comment: @whytheq feel free to edit my answer to one working. It is always difficult to write MDX without having the cube available for cross checking.

Comment: +1 @FrankPI - (this language is very addictive) ....thanks for extra info : so in my OP `lag` _is_ working but my new member is randomly chucked into the hierarchy `[Date].[Date - Calendar Month]` so who knows where it is then lagging to ?

Comment: @whytheq `Item(0)`, applied to a set, returns the first tuple of the set, and `Item(0)`, applied to a tuple, returns the first member of the tuple. Hence, if you apply `.Item(0).Item(0)` to a one dimensional one element set, you get the (one and only) member contained in it.

Comment: @whytheq Actually, the way it was defined by you, the new member would be a sibling of the "All" member of the hierarchy, thus, it has a well defined position. But I am not sure if `Lag` works with calculated members at all. Anyway, using calculated members, you will not get the `lag` function to work properly with calculated members, and the workaround is using sets.

Comment: @FrankPI ....ok based on explanation of `Item` I will re-edit my edit to your answer as I think it is more defensive to include both `.Item(0)`s ....

Comment: @FrankPI ...lol ...I just amended my original script for LastMth calculated member to this: `MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Year].&[2012].[LastMth] AS` ...left everything else unchanged. So now Oct-2013 has 2012 as it parent !! Never realised this about calculated members: seems like I can make any item it's parent....how do I make it part of an existing level? or is that not possible?

Comment: @frankPI - if `All` is it's parent in the OP then why does this happen? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269303/how-to-always-find-the-parent-of-a-calculated-member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269303/how-to-always-find-the-parent-of-a-calculated-member)

Comment: @whytheq To make a calculated member part of a level, make it a child of a member on the parent level. However, relationships like being a sibling are not very reliable in Analysis Services for calculated members.