# How to always find the parent of a calculated member

Tags: mdx

This seems pretty logical:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Year].&[2013].[LastMth] AS
    IIF(
       Day(Now()) = 1,
       TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2).Item(1),
       TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2).Item(0)
       )
SELECT
    NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth],
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth].PARENT
    }
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[BillableIncome]
    ON ROWS 
FROM [ourCube]
```

I specify the parent of the calculated member in the first line of the script - so my member LastMth has 2013 as it's parent and sure enough the result set throws back the total for 2013 as well as the last month.

If I make it's parent 2012 in the first line:

```
 WITH 
    MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Year].&[2012].[LastMth] AS
        IIF(
...
...
```

...it doesn't worry about where I get LastMth from (2013) and makes 2012 it's parent as instructed - slightly bizarre but understandable behaviour.

The following returns an empty set for the parent - I thought the parent would be `[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[(All)]`? What is the parent and how can I expose it's value?

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth] AS
    IIF(
       Day(Now()) = 1,
       TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2).Item(1),
       TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2).Item(0)
       )
SELECT
    NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth],
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastMth].PARENT
    }
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
        [Measures].[BillableIncome]
    ON ROWS 
FROM [ourCube]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not state a parent for a calculated member, it gets a **sibling** of the `All` member, not a child of it.

As an aside: I found that most client tools - including Excel - do not expect `All` to have siblings, and thus if you `create` a calculated member in the calculation script (as opposed to just defining it in the `WITH` clause of a statement), do not display these, even if they are instructed to show calculated members.

Comment: we have `Pyramid` and `Excel 2010`. If I can do something in Excel I will but being able to just copy and paste an MDX script into a Pyramid dashboard is very attractive: why don't MS add this to Excel's OLAP capabilities.

Comment: +1...back to your answer: so because it is a sibling of `All` this means in my script when I do `.PARENT` it's got nowhere to go - hence the empty result set ?

Comment: Yes. Let's say, if you do not give it a parent when you create the member, it has none.